# A ? Sign shows instead of references in the jss template of rticlespackage

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, citations

I have problems adding References to the jss template. I have use the elsevier template with no problem. I also tried changin the @reference to \cite{references} or \citep{references} but a ? Sign appears where the references should be. I feel I am not pointing to the .bib file in the right way. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

As an example I have the following code from the paper I am trying to write with the citation in the last word of the last paragraph:

```
---
author:
  - name: Derek Corcoran
    affiliation: University of Missouri
    address: >
    First line
    Second line
email: corcoranbarriosd@missouri.edu
url: http://rstudio.com

formatted: "Selecting priority areas from diversity and individual species abundance \\pkg{DiversityOccupancy}"
short:     "\\pkg{DiversityOccupancy}: Selecting Priority Areas"
abstract: >
Lately occupancy modeling has been vastly used as a tool for ecological research and management planing. However mostly it is used by interpreting single species models. We present the \pkg{DiversityOccupancy} in the \proglang{R} environment. The objective of this package is to simultaneously model factors associated with occupancy and abundance of individual species using a detection history file, and to use predicted abundances to calculate species diversity for each sampling site. The package then models factor(s) associated with among-site species diversity, which can then be combined with spatial data to identify areas that contain both high abundance of species of conservation concern and high species diversity.
keywords:
# at least one keyword must be supplied
formatted: [ "\\pkg{DiversityOccupancy}", Occupancy Modeling, "\\proglang{R}"]
plain:     [keywords, not capitalized, Occupancy modeling]
preamble: >
\usepackage{amsmath}
output:
  rticles::jss_article:
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: Derek.bib
---




# Introduction

In the last decade, Occupancy modeling has been used more and more as a 
method to account for how species respond to environmental or anthropogenic 
factors. It has also been shown to be useful as a species distribution 
modeling tool when species have imperfect detection 
\cite{mackenzie_estimating_2002}.
```

In my .bib file, the paper is formated like this:

```
@article{mackenzie_estimating_2002,
    title = {Estimating site occupancy rates when detection probabilities are less than one},
    volume = {83},
    url = {http://www.esajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1890/0012-9658(2002)083%5B2248:ESORWD%5D2.0.CO%3B2},
    number = {8},
    urldate = {2016-01-13},
    journal = {Ecology},
    author = {MacKenzie, Darryl I. and Nichols, James D. and Lachman, Gideon B. and Droege, Sam and Andrew Royle, J. and Langtimm, Catherine A.},
    year = {2002},
    pages = {2248--2255},
    file = {[PDF] de uvm.edu:/home/derek/.zotero/zotero/b7w3ygs6.default/zotero/storage/HSJAQTQG/MacKenzie et al. - 2002 - Estimating site occupancy rates when detection pro.pdf:application/pdf;Snapshot:/home/derek/.zotero/zotero/b7w3ygs6.default/zotero/storage/G45M4BNP/abstract.html:text/html}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code that replicates the problem?

Comment: @Werner I am sorry, I don't know how I missed your reply, this is why it took long for me to add the example. If you need I can send you the .bib file